# plot small region of a large polygon map in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have a shapefile which I fortified and plotted in ggplot2 using `geom_polygon`. How can I plot only a small region of this map?

My full map looks fine, but my small region is messed up.

Here is a working example:
This small shapefile can be obtained from:

http://www.mappinghacks.com/data/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.2.zip

```
#read data
spf<-readOGR(getwd(),"TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.2")
spf@data$id<-rownames(spf@data)

#fortify
spf1<-fortify(spf,region="id")

#full plot
ggplot(spf1)+geom_polygon(aes(long,lat,group=group),colour="grey90")
```

[image: fullplot]

```
#subset plot #this is messy since polygons are broken
ggplot(spf1)+geom_polygon(aes(long,lat,group=group),colour="grey90")+
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2, 2))+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(50, 51))
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry. Forgot to declare the libraries.

`require(rgdal)`
`require(ggplot2)`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `limits` argument in `scale_x_...` and `scale_y...` sets the limits of the scale. Any values outside these limits are not drawn (the underlying data is dropped). This includes elements (such as a polygon) which may only be partially outside these limits.

If you want to *zoom* the plot in by setting the limits on the coordinates, then use the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments to a `coord_....` function, From [`?coord_cartesian`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/coord_cartesian.html)

> Setting limits on the coordinate system will zoom the plot (like you're looking at it with a magnifying glass), and will not change the underlying data like setting limits on a scale will.

In your case you have a `map`, and you can use `coord_map`, which will project your data using a map projection.

eg

```
ggplot(spf1, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour  = 'grey90') +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-2, 2),ylim = c(50, 51))
```

[image]

Comment: An additional comment is that, the `coord_map` needs coordinates as longitude-latitude or it needs a specific projection to be specified. For UTM coordinates, its better to use `coord_cartesian`.

Comment: Any ideas about how to use this together with `coord_fixed`?