# ggplot2 polygon world map centred with limits gives funny edges

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the below code I generate a map centred on Washington DC.  solution based on  [kohske's solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620862/use-different-center-than-the-prime-meridian-in-plotting-a-world-map).  I have changed `geom_path` to `geom_polygon` as I want to colour the countries.

All is well and good until I want add the `scale_x_continuous` (commented so you can see that there's no problem when it is left out), this makes Antarctica and China look very strange, i guess because the polygons have been trimmed?

[image]

Is there a known workaround for this?  Help is appreciated.

```
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)

home_country_longitude <- -77.03

mp1 <- fortify(map(fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE))
mp2 <- mp1

mp2$long <- mp2$long + 360
mp2$group <- mp2$group + max(mp2$group) + 1

mp <- rbind(mp1, mp2)

if(home_country_longitude < 0){
  mp$long <- mp$long - (360 + home_country_longitude)
} else {
  mp$long <- mp$long + home_country_longitude
}

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = mp) +
  #scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-180, 180)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#090D2A"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `coord_map`, like this. Full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323832/plot-small-region-of-a-large-polygon-map-in-ggplot2).

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = mp) +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-180, 180)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: cheers champ, will confirm this tomorrow morning and accept once it works